# Slope of Tangent Passing Through Point

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given the equation of the curve $y=x^2+x$ and the requirement that the tangent to this curve passes through $(2, -3)$, what are the possible equations of the tangent lines?

I started by differentiating the curve: $ y'=2x+1$. Then I let the point of tangency be $(a, a^2+a)$.

After solving the equations, I ended up finding the equations of the tangents to the curve passing through $(2, -3)$ to be: $y=11x-25$ and $y=-x-1$.

edit: found the points of tangency to be $(5, 30)$ and $(-1, 0)$

Am I correct? Are there more solutions?

Comment: Well these lines do have (2,-3) on them. Just check the derivatives match. Or even easier make a graph of the two lines and the parabola on a graphing calculator. Maybe add to your question the values of a,a^2+a for each of the two lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer: Yes, you are correct.**

**Long Answer:**

In this case, we know we need to find the lines tangent to the curve that go through some point, so I would begin by using the elementary point-slope equation to figure out the equation for y in the original function that meets those conditions.

$$y - y_1 = m(x - x_1)$$

The derivative is the slope at some x on the curve, so plug its function in for m. Use the points given in the problem for $x_1$ and $y_1$ respectively:

$$y - (-3) = (2x + 1)(x - 2)$$

Simplify:

$$y + 3 = 2x^2 - 3x - 2$$

Solve for y:

$$y = 2x^2 - 3x - 5$$

Now that we have what y must be in relation to x for the tangent line to meet the conditions given, we can plug it in to the original equation to find the desired values of x on the curve:

$$2x^2 - 3x - 5 = x^2 + x$$

Subtract $x^2 + x$ from both sides:

$$x^2 - 4x - 5 = 0$$

From the quadratic formula, we know that:

$$x = \frac{4 ± \sqrt{36}}{2}$$

Therefore $x = 5$ and $x = -1$, which when plugged into your original function, gives the points you calculated in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

First we have:

$$y = x^2 + x$$
$$y' = 2x + 1$$
$$p = (2,-3)$$
Next we must construct two projective right-angle triangles with the hypotenuse connecting p to points m (on the left) and n (on the right). For m:
$$(-x_m + 2)(-y'_m) - 3 = y_m$$
$y'_m$ is negated because we are looking at it from the right and $x_m$ is negated because we want the absolute value of the base. This simplifies to:
$$(x_m - 2)y'_m - 3 = y_m$$
Which is the same as the formula for n:
$$(x_n - 2)y'_n - 3 = y_n$$
So we can generalize:
$$(x - 2)y' - 3 = y$$
But at both m and n the derivative of the curve and the value of y is the same as that for the respective line so, substituting:
$$(x - 2)(2x + 1) - 3 = x^2 + x$$
Which, as stated by CaptainObvious is a quadratic with solutions 5 and -1, so the y values are 0 and 30. This allows us to compute the gradients of mp and pn:
$$\frac{0 - 3}{2 - -1} = -1$$
$$\frac{30 - -3}{5 - 2} = 11$$
Which are the same values you get if you substitute -1 and 5 into the derivative of the curve. This was the stated condition.

Answer (score 0):

You have an equation for your slope in $y'$ and you have a point. I would advise you to use point-slope form $y-y_0=y'(x-x_0)$.